# Creating an XML for Wordpress custom post type and need some clarification with the data shown in the XML child elements

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have already created the following code:

```
<?php
/**
 * generate XML feed for custom post type "product"
 */
header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');

// Create a new XML document
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');

// Create the root element
$root = $xml->createElement('products');
$root = $xml->appendChild($root);

// Get all the "product" custom post type posts
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);

// Loop through the posts and create XML elements for each product
if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        
        // Create a product element
        $product = $xml->createElement('product');
        $product = $root->appendChild($product);

        // Add custom fields as XML elements
        $product->appendChild($xml->createElement('title', get_the_title()));
        //$product->appendChild($xml->createElement('price', get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'price', true)));
        //$product->appendChild($xml->createElement('description', get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'description', true)));
        // Add other custom fields in a similar manner
    }
}

// Output the XML content
echo $xml->saveXML();

?>
```

This seems to be working fine. Here is a sample of a product element generated in my XML from the above code:

```
<product>
<title>G704</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/css/language-selector.css?v=3.3.1" type="text/css" media="all"/>
</product>
```

All I want to do is prevent the following line from my XML which is generated the same for all products in the XML tree

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/css/language-selector.css?v=3.3.1" type="text/css" media="all"/>
```

Any ideas why this is being generated and solutions on how I could get rid of?

Thanks in advance,

George.

Comment: This plugin sitepress-multilingual-cms is somewhat affecting the query so its added. If you debug  $product in the loop can you see if the link tag is already added ? You can also try with get_posts() instead of wp_query

Comment: Hello @Snuffy, I just tried that, and it outputted the same, unfortunately.